# Print array with angular js directives

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'd like to parse an json and print it on page with angular js. I could print array with ng-repeat directivie but there are nested arrays and couldn't print them properly. Here is the json with arrays;

```
   [{ 
        'adi':'serhat', 
        'adres':'Tuzla/İSTANBUL', 
        'telefon':[ {'numara':'(0216) 38343', 'dahili':['426']} ],
    },
    {
        'adi':'ali', 
        'adres':'Taksim/İSTANBUL', 
        'telefon':[{'numara':'(0212) 3893753','dahili':['2346','2220']}]
    }]
```

I would like to print the 'dahili' arrays. I could print them as a string with;

```
{{numarasi.dahili | json}}
```

But I want to print each item in array how can I do that? For example in a span tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <table>
         <tr  ng-repeat="elem in numarasi">
              <td  ng-repeat="innerelem in elem.telefon">
                <span>{{innerelem.dahili}}</span>
              </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Use [ng-repeat.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)